# Get value from inheritance out of a collection

Tags: c#, class

I created classes that derive from a parent class looking like this.

```
class Usability
{
    public string useName = "404";
}
```

and

```
class Heal : Usability
{
    public string useName = "drink";
}
```

when putting multiple in a Dictionary

```
    public Dictionary<int, Usability> useDict = new();
```

and then accessing useName via

```
foreach(var usability in item.usabilitys)
            {
                Console.Write(usability.useName);
            }
```

allways prints "404". When using

```
foreach(Heal usability in item.usabilitys)
            {
                Console.Write(usability.useName);
            }
```

instead prints "drink". There are functions and more data included in sub classes but this breaks down the problem as much as possible.

Comment: You should receive a compiler warning. Don't ignore them. Google for one and you will eventually learn without the need to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

`useName` is the *field*, and fields can't be inherited.

You can use the properties instead of the fields:

```cs
public class Base
{
    public virtual string Name { get; } = "404";
}

public class Inheritor : Base
{
    public override string Name { get; } = "drink";
}
```

You *must* mark the base property as a *virtual* to override it in the class `Inheritor`.

Properties is just syntax sugar to getter and setter methods, so the property `Name` is really compiled to the method `get_Name`.

When you mark the property as the *virtual* you really make virtual method `get_Name` and you can override it.